# PDF reader for WP7

Tags: pdf, windows-phone-7

Are there any free PDF reader API's available for WP7? I need to read and display a PDF file, just like how Acrobat reader does.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's nothing built into Windows Phone 7 to display PDF files and I'm not aware of any free compatible libraries (that's not to say there isn't one). If you're able to host the PDF files online, then you can link to that and have the user use the `Acrobat Reader` app to read it.

```
   WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
   wbt.Url = @"http:\\www.example.com\mypdffile.pdf
   wbt.Show();
```

Comment: Well Acrobat reader in WP7 sucks big time. There's no way you can traverse to a particular page in PDF, no search, nor is there a way to make Acrobat remember last read page. On the other side Android has al of these features. I wish to create an app that will encompass Acrobat reader and provide all these functionality. Looks like I am all alone on this venture.

Comment: ye it sucks, maybe some webservice that convert pdf to html?

Comment: Yup, it's not the greatest solution. You could use Google Docs PDF Viewer - http://docs.google.com/viewer and pass in the URL. Then display this in a `WebBrowser` component on your page. I'm not sure if it's any more versatile than the Acrobat app, but might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharpwp7.codeplex.com/)